# Change a variable value every 10 second

Tags: javascript, variables

I've a set of array.

```
var markers = [
    { lat: 1.55851, lng: 103.63217, name: "Bus A" },
    { lat: 1.56525, lng: 103.63487, name: "Bus B" },
    { lat: 1.55843, lng: 103.64669, name: "Bus C" },
];
```

How do I change the lat and lng value every 10 second? Maybe I get the value from another set of array and assign to lat and lng every 10 sec.

Comment: Is that really java ? Are you aware that java is to javascript what car is to carrot ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java ?

Comment: @Satya This is not helpful...

Comment: Looks like javascript, change java in heading to javascript and perhaps you could remove tag java

Comment: This would still be closed : the question is too vague. "Maybe" ? Really ?

Comment: I've voted to close because you do not provide enough information. You should at least have mentioned the source of the lat and lngs that you want to change to and from.  Are they random? Are they seeded from somewhere? What/where/how/when?!

Comment: If you get some other values from another array, why not set the markers array when the other one is updated? Scheduling something every 10 seconds for assigning a value seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of your answer would be to use `setInterval`, which runs a block of code at regular intervals.

In your case you might do something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Get your new lat and lng values from somewhere
    val newLat = someOtherArray[0].lat

    // Now set them on the markers array (this is a very brief example)
    markers[0].lat = newLat;
}, 10 * 1000 /* interval is in milliseconds */ );
```

This will invoke the function every 10 seconds.  So you'd need to write a body for the function which would change your `markers` values to whatever you want (presumably the current values according to "another set of arrays").  And then this would work, as your function would run regularly and keep `markers` up to date.